# Magento 2 - How to add redirect link to login link?

Tags: magento2, login, redirect

I created a new CMS site `newsletter-abo` and placed a text on it which shows this:

> Please *login* to access this site.

The word "login" points to `/customer/account/login`.

If the customer clicks on this link, then he gets redirected to the login site.

We need the customer to get redirected back to the `newsletter-abo` site after the login.

I know you can do this by adding a encrypted text to the URL, but I don't know how I can do it.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code for this:

```
$url  = $this->getUrl('*/*/*', ['_current' => true, '_use_rewrite' => true]);
$login_url = $block->getUrl('customer/account/login', array('referer' => base64_encode($url)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create your custom controller class to which you point from your CMS page. Inject `Magento\Framework\UrlInterface` in the controller constructor and add the following piece of code in the execute method:

```php
public function execute()
{
    $loginRoute = $this->urlInterface
        ->getUrl('customer/account/login',
        ['referer' => base64_encode($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl())]
    );
    $redirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    $redirect->setUrl($loginRoute);

    return $redirect;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call observer after successfull customer_login.

> Step 1:- Please create events.xml file under path
> PackageName/Module/etc/frontend/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_login">
        <observer name="customer_login_success" instance="PackageName\Module\Observer\CustomerLogin" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> Step 2: Create CustomerLogin.php file under path
> PackageName/Module/Observer/

```
<?php
namespace PackageName\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CustomerLogin implements ObserverInterface
{
     /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory
     */
    protected $responseFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory
    ) {
        $this->responseFactory = $responseFactory;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $redirectUrl = 'https://domain.com/newsletter-abo'; // add your redirect url
        $resultRedirect = $this->responseFactory->create();
        $resultRedirect->setRedirect($redirectUrl)->sendResponse('200');
        exit();
    }
}
```

With the above you can redirect as per you want after login.

Comment: But this will always redirect to newsletter-abo. I only need to redirect after a link was clicked.